# Error code board and boards.txt? Formatting error? cannot verify alarm.txt or any

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, shields

Arduino: 1.8.8 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

Error reading file (E:\arduino\arduino-1.8.8\hardware\arduino\avr**\boards.txt:0**): **Invalid line format, should be 'key=value'**

Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.[/b]

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

I was trying to do this experiment: http://wirebeings.com/arduino-intruder-alarm.html

but with Arduino Uno + geeetech iduino yun shield setup.

http://www.geeetech.com/wiki/index.php/Iduino_Yun_Shield

Please help (also short do you short the two pins properly?)

this is the board.txt file:

```
unoyun.name=Arduino Uno --Iduino Yún
unoyun.upload.via_ssh=true
unoyun.vid.0=0x2341
unoyun.pid.0=0x0043
unoyun.vid.1=0x2341
unoyun.pid.1=0x0001
unoyun.upload.tool=avrdude
unoyun.upload.protocol=arduino
unoyun.upload.maximum_size=32256
unoyun.upload.maximum_data_size=2048
unoyun.upload.speed=57600
unoyun.upload.disable_flushing=true
unoyun.upload.use_1200bps_touch=true
unoyun.upload.wait_for_upload_port=true
unoyun.bootloader.tool=avrdude
unoyun.bootloader.low_fuses=0xff
unoyun.bootloader.high_fuses=0xde
unoyun.bootloader.extended_fuses=0x05
unoyun.bootloader.file=optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex
unoyun.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
unoyun.bootloader.lock_bits=0x0F
unoyun.build.mcu=atmega328p
unoyun.build.f_cpu=16000000L
unoyun.build.board=AVR_YUN
unoyun.build.core=arduino
unoyun.build.variant=standard
```

and this is the boards.txt file:

```
# See: http://code.google.com/p/arduino/wiki/Platforms

menu.cpu=Processor

##############################################################

yun.name=Arduino Yún
yun.upload.via_ssh=true

yun.vid.0=0x2341
yun.pid.0=0x0041
yun.vid.1=0x2341
yun.pid.1=0x8041
yun.vid.2=0x2A03
yun.pid.2=0x0041
yun.vid.3=0x2A03
yun.pid.3=0x8041

yun.upload.tool=avrdude
yun.upload.protocol=avr109
yun.upload.maximum_size=28672
yun.upload.maximum_data_size=2560
yun.upload.speed=57600
yun.upload.disable_flushing=true
yun.upload.use_1200bps_touch=true
yun.upload.wait_for_upload_port=true

yun.bootloader.tool=avrdude
yun.bootloader.low_fuses=0xff
yun.bootloader.high_fuses=0xd8
yun.bootloader.extended_fuses=0xfb
yun.bootloader.file=caterina/Caterina-Yun.hex
yun.bootloader.noblink=caterina/Caterina-Yun-noblink.hex
yun.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
yun.bootloader.lock_bits=0x2F

yun.build.mcu=atmega32u4
yun.build.f_cpu=16000000L
yun.build.vid=0x2341
yun.build.pid=0x8041
yun.build.usb_product="Arduino Yun"
yun.build.board=AVR_YUN
yun.build.core=arduino
yun.build.variant=yun
yun.build.extra_flags={build.usb_flags}

##############################################################

uno.name=Arduino/Genuino Uno

uno.vid.0=0x2341
uno.pid.0=0x0043
uno.vid.1=0x2341
uno.pid.1=0x0001
uno.vid.2=0x2A03
uno.pid.2=0x0043
uno.vid.3=0x2341
uno.pid.3=0x0243

uno.upload.tool=avrdude
uno.upload.protocol=arduino
uno.upload.maximum_size=32256
uno.upload.maximum_data_size=2048
uno.upload.speed=115200

uno.bootloader.tool=avrdude
uno.bootloader.low_fuses=0xFF
uno.bootloader.high_fuses=0xDE
uno.bootloader.extended_fuses=0xFD
uno.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
uno.bootloader.lock_bits=0x0F
uno.bootloader.file=optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex

uno.build.mcu=atmega328p
uno.build.f_cpu=16000000L
uno.build.board=AVR_UNO
uno.build.core=arduino
uno.build.variant=standard

##############################################################

diecimila.name=Arduino Duemilanove or Diecimila

diecimila.upload.tool=avrdude
diecimila.upload.protocol=arduino

diecimila.bootloader.tool=avrdude
diecimila.bootloader.low_fuses=0xFF
diecimila.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
diecimila.bootloader.lock_bits=0x0F

diecimila.build.f_cpu=16000000L
diecimila.build.board=AVR_DUEMILANOVE
diecimila.build.core=arduino
diecimila.build.variant=standard
```

Comment: two boards.txt files or did I edit it wrong and the "and this is the boards.txt file:" is inside your board.txt file?

Comment: two files

both in \hardware\avr - board.txt or boards.txt file worked

Answer (score 0):

nvm, apparently some guys suggesting utf-8 bom encoding change or something because I saw 1 question related to this

(it didn't work)

then I changed it to utf-8 encoding

(both done through notepad++)

it worked.

Answer (score 0):

John Doe, thanks for the tip about utf-8.

I just ran into this exact problem.  boards.txt had been hand-edited in Windows Notepad and saved as utf-8 and was throwing this error.

```
Arduino: 1.8.10 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"  
loading hardware from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware: 
loading package arduino: loading platform release: 
Error reading file (C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino
\hardware\arduino\avr\boards.txt:0): 
Invalid line format, should be 'key=value'
```

I changed the text file format to ANSI and saved, and that fixed the problem, able to compile.  At this point, guessing that maybe changing format merely cleaned up a defect, I saved again to utf-8, but it broke again.  Thus back to ANSI.